# What does "Kan" mean in "Kan operations"?

Tags: cubical-type-theory

I'm studying Cubical Type Theory and I see the word "Kan operations" ([ref1](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/talks/POPL18-Tutorial.pdf), [ref2](https://github.com/RedPRL/redtt/issues/247), [ref3](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2018/12/06/cubical-agda/), and there are many more), which is related to "adding a cap to a tube" (can be also explained as "given a path between `a` and `b`, and two paths that are between `a` and `c`/`b` and `d` respectively, we can use Kan operations to get a path between `c` and `d`").

I wonder if there's any references that can explain where this "Kan" word come from -- what does it mean? Is that "Kan extensions" in Category theory?

Comment: It’s a personal name. Daniel Kan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kan operations are likely named after [Daniel M. Kan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Kan), in analogy to concepts such as [Kan extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan_extension), [Kan complexes, Kan fibrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan_fibration), [Kan condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-category#Definition), and many more. Kan also introduced [adjoint functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors).

Comment: Does that mean "filling something" then?

Comment: Kan operation seems to be shorthand for Kan filling operation, but I don’t really know anything about this area.